# Hide the Uploaded PHoto from Timeline

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api

I am building a script that will upload a cover image based on the changes in the number of fans of a page.

When the photo is uploaded it appears on the time line.

Is there any way i can remove it from appearing from the Timeline.

```
$photo = FCPATH . "assets/img/image(" . rand(1, 3) . ").jpg";

    $this->facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);

    $photo_uploaded = $this->facebook->api("/" . $page_id . "/photos", "POST", array
        ('access_token' => $this->input->get('access_token'), 'source' => '@' . $photo));

    $this->facebook->api("/" . $page_id, "POST", array(
        'access_token' => $this->input->get('access_token'),
        'cover' => $photo_uploaded['id'],
        'offset_y' => 0));

    $this->facebook->api("/" . $photo_uploaded['id'], "DELETE", array('access_token' =>
            $this->input->get('access_token')));

    $this->manager->setFansCount($page_id, $data['likes']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `no_feed_story` parameter and set to `true` to the cover image API call to suppress the story, and add `no_story` and set to `true` to suppress the Photo Upload story (instead of deleting it).

E.g.

```
$this->facebook->api("/" . $page_id, "POST", array(
    'access_token' => $this->input->get('access_token'),
    'cover' => $photo_uploaded['id'],
    'offset_y' => 0
    'no_feed_story' => true ));
```

Comment: thanks a lot. will try it out and get back to you :D